# sorting files in a folder by specified sub-string of the filename using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

Is there a way to sort files in a folder using VBA using the LAST 3 characters of the file name only. So that for example files named a_123_abds.xls and b_234_gbds.pdf  are listed together.

Comment: Windows Explorer does the sorting in its folders. While you use Windows Explorer its rules can't be over-written. You might create a list box that pops up on your screen showing a list of files. Such a list could be sorted any way you want, including the way you describe. You could use VBA to manage the list box as well as the list.

Comment: As an alternative, consider changing the files names temporarily so that they are shown in the sequence you want by Windows Explorer. You can do that with VBA. You might even create a dedicated folder and place specially named shortcuts to the files into it. The shortcuts need not have the same names as the files they open, and Windows Explorer would show them sorted in the sequence dictated by their names.

Comment: Sorry for the delay in getting back. Thanks for the tips. In the end I went with the option of creating dedicated folders with parts of the file name and then copying the files into it. The issue was that there would be multiple files with the same 3 characters. Thanks!